# Twig Code for a List of all files which are in {{file_location}} Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, directory, twig, readdir

So far I have managed to show "the last file" in my twig view, and all of them over the controller which appears on my page at first line before the header.  Now, I need to display all in the twig view.

This is my code:

**controller**

```
public function frmyfilesAction(Request $request)    { $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession(); $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); $repository = $em->getRepository('redlabLabelBundle:Users');
    if ($session->has('login')) 
    {
        $login = $session->get('login');
        $username = $login->getUsername();
        $password = $login->getPassword();
        $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('userName' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        $dir = $user->getServer();

        if ($dh = opendir($dir))
        {
            $store_array = array() ;
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)    
            {
                echo $file . "</br>";
                $store_array = $file;
            }
            $mefil = $store_array;
                                }
            closedir($dh);

            return $this->render('redlabLabelBundle:Advert:frmyfiles.html.twig', array('mifil'=> $mefil,'name' => $user->getFirstName(),'fhost' => $user->getServer());
        }
        return $this->render('redlabLabelBundle:Advert:radiofr.html.twig'); }
```

**twig view**

```
 {%block body %} <div class="container">
     <h2>Ici sont stoqués tous tes fichiers {{name}}</h2></br></br>     <h4>Mon Dossier {{fhost}}<h4>   </br>

     <a href="{{fhost}}{{mifil}}">{{mifil}} </a>    </br></br></br>     </br></br></br>

     </div>  <a href="{{path('redlab_platform_logout')}}"
     >Déconnection</a></br></br></br></br>
 {%endblock%}
```

--

How do I bring ALL the data from the while loop in the array, so that I can use it in the twig view?

Comment: {{file_location}} is coming from the Controller and automaticly change by logged ID

Comment: I see the problem ... in my twig view there is no loop ... and ... in my controller the $mefil is getting all file name but only store the last one befor closedir .... so when the controller render the view he only pass the last one to the twig file and the twig file has only one line witch says oh i have to print out $mefil ... I understand my failure but I'm searching and searching truth the web  just can't find how to fix it please help me out if ya understand my problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig is designed to render a view there is no Twig native function to read file names.
You should get the file names in your crontroller (or even better in a service) and then send the data to your view.
And if you really want to use Twig to do so, yes you will have to write a Twig extension but it's a very very very bad idea...

Comment: Hi and thank you well yes getting the name over the controller is of course the best idee - i manage to do it but i can t get all those names in my view even if i got them in my controller and when I'm searching on the web for solution all pages are telling you haw to do that with php but with php is easy just dont understand how to make it with Symfony ... PS I have re edit my question so it may be more clear to understand !

Comment: @OseCrea if you haven't done so, I'd recommend you to have a read about  MVC pattern, which is what Symfony2/3 is based around; Twig should only present the data collected in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The *final solution* that worked is simple; just replace the twig yiew with this code:

```
{%block body %}
<div class="container">

    <h2>Ici sont stoqués tous tes fichiers {{name}}</h2></br></br>
    <h4>Mon Dossier {{fhost}}<h4>
    </br>

    {% for item in mifil %}
        <li><a href="{{fhost}}{{item}}">{{item}} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}

    </br></br></br>
    </br></br></br>
</div> 
<a href="{{path('redlab_platform_logout')}}" >Déconnection</a></br></br></br></br>
{%endblock%}
```